# Can I run Parallels Desktop Mac 5 on OS X Snow Leopard Server?

Tags: virtualization, osx-snow-leopard

Anyone know if I can run Parallels Desktop Mac 5 on OS X Snow Leopard Server?

I know Parallels make a Mac OS X Server product, but I'm interested in whether their desktop product will install and run fine.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

You can run Parallels Desktop 5 for Mac on Snow Leopard Server, but it should only be used to virtualize client OSes or for non-production server OSes. You will likely find some serious roadblocks to virtualizing HP servers to a Mac mini if you try to do it with the Parallels Desktop and I would not assume it'll be reliable enough for virtualizing servers.

Yes, you'll be paying a price for it, but by using Parallels Server you should be gaining higher performance, lower overhead, and far better configuration & management capabilities (incl. image management, cloning, scripting, etc.), not to mention a setup intended for enterprise environments.

If you haven't already, compare [Parallels Desktop 5 for Mac's features](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/features/) with [Parallels Server for Mac's features](http://www.parallels.com/products/server/mac/features/). I'd also suggest getting in touch with their sales team and describing exactly what your setup is and what you'd like it to be to see if they think there's any way Parallels Desktop could get you there.

Answer (score 1):

sure You can run it, and unless You need to have some special ports opened on the virtualised OS (like 511 ...) you are gonna be fine. Problem of course is with user accounts, since the Parallels does not run as a Server process, thus You mast have a user permanently logged into the Server and have the Parallels VM running from there.

Answer (score 0):

Their ad campaign says "You love Snow Leopard, You need Windows 7", so I'm guessing that's your answer right there, but you can always download the trial and see if it works.

Comment: Actually no I can't because I don't have Snow Leopard Server. I'm thinking of replacing a rack of very, very old HP servers with a Mac Mini.